# R operation on matrices with if to avoid NaN warning

Tags: r, matrix

I have two matrices, pt1 and pt2, with the sample below:

```
pt1[1,] = 9.819 1.839 1.542 1.236 1.137 0.774 0.774 0.608 0.527 0.327 0.324 0.245 0.133 0.111 0.110 0.067 0.038 0.018 0.007 0.002 0.000 0.000
pt2[1,] = 9.9770359 1.8361173 1.6109915 1.2507719 1.0475069 0.7834792 0.7832150 0.6610241 0.5318586 0.3857874 0.3084728 0.2700538 0.1439364 0.1220980 0.1056596 0.0679037 0.0373881 0.0220959 0.0068046 0.0018711 0.0000000 0.0000000
```

I have to perform log operation like that:

```
rt2 <- log(pt2/pt1)*0.5
```

However, as expected, the last two values will produce NaN since pt1 values are zero (division by zero). That showed a warning:

```
Warning message:
In log(pt2/pt1) : NaNs produced
```

I used `ifelse` to correct that (and expecting it to remove the warning):

```
r2 <- ifelse(pt1==0 | pt2==0, 0, log(pt2/pt1)*0.5)
```

The NaN are no longer produced, however the warning is still shown.

What should I do to avoid the warning?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method using subscripting:

```
# get vector of proper length
r2 <- numeric(length(pt1))
# get logical vector of same length for fill in indicator
fillins <- pt1 != 0 & pt2 != 0
# fill in values
r2[fillins] <- log(pt2[fillins] / pt1[fillins]) * 0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `suppressWarnings()`:

```
pt1 <- matrix(rnorm(2200), nrow = 100)
pt2 <- matrix(rnorm(2200), nrow = 100)
rt2 <- suppressWarnings(log(pt2/pt1)*0.5)
head(rt2[,1:5],2)
           [,1]      [,2] [,3]       [,4]   [,5]
[1,] -0.1209207 0.8211299  NaN -0.3271424    NaN
[2,] -0.3916372       NaN  NaN        NaN 1.1085

rt2[is.na(rt2)] <- 0
head(rt2[,1:5],2)
           [,1]      [,2] [,3]       [,4]   [,5]
[1,] -0.1209207 0.8211299    0 -0.3271424 0.0000
[2,] -0.3916372 0.0000000    0  0.0000000 1.1085
```

I hope this helps.